# how to understand why wamp is so slow on windows?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, symfony, wamp

Developing on localhost with wamp last version and windows 7, the response average time is 10s versus 0.5s on ubuntu 14.04 + LAMP. I am also using symfony in both cases.

I have found many posts explaning I could add stuff in hosts file, configure mysqlconnect, load php as an apache module, etc... Nothing works.

So my question is not what else to do but how to understand what is slow ? How can I figure out what is taking time ? (my symfony timeline is not precise enough).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your Ubuntu running on the same (or same spec) box as your wampp stack? Is the configuration the same?

Comment: What is the spec of the PC you are running this on? Have you tried running `Resource Monitor` to see if Memory is an issue

Comment: my windows computer is actually more performant: 3GB or ram against 1GB, 250GB hard drive againts 10GB, 2GHZ in both cases... this is not the reason. wamp is slow on windows localhost and many have already experienced this but I have the impression I am doing black magic here...